# Find the correct object in JSON and edit values of this object C# Json.Linq

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON file (list.json):

```
[
    {
        "groupID": "12345",
        "subID": "71",
        "stock": false,
        "price": "32.21"
    },
    {
        "groupID": "12345",
        "subID": "25",
        "stock": false,
        "price": "12.94"
    }
]
```

What a I like to do is, that I edit the "stock" value of one specific object. So if the value of stock is false I like to change it to true and if its true I like to change to false.

I tried to start but I have already at the beginning a big problem. I get already while the parsing a **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : 'Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.'**. I believe it happens because the JSON starts with an array.

My method:

```
public void EditJSON (string GroupID, string SubID)
        {
            JObject JSONnew = JObject.Parse(list.json);

            if (*stock is true*)
            {
              *change stock to false*
            } 

            if (*stock is false*)
            {
              *change stock to ture*
            }

        }
```

How I can find in the JSON the correct object by using the GroupID and the SubID and edit the value of stock from false to true or the opposit?

Comment: I mean find the object in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse your JSON to [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm), then filter items by `groupID` and `subID` values. Finally enumerate the filtered items one by one and change a `stock` value, if needed

```cs
var items = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
var filtered = items.Where(i => i["groupID"]?.Value<int>() == 12345 && i["subID"]?.Value<int>() == 25);
foreach (var item in filtered)
{
    var stock = item["stock"]?.Value<bool>();
    if (stock == null)
        continue;

    if (stock.Value)
        item["stock"] = false;
    else
        item["stock"] = true;
}

Console.WriteLine(items);
```

Comment: Works so far. However, we both have one small fault. As soon as "stock" is changed to false, it will be changed back to true in the next if block. I think with a double if block with break it is better

Comment: There's one more problem.  In the end only this array range is changed and not this array range in the whole JSON.  The only thing I can think of now is to delete this array in the json and add at the end the edited array again. 
 
Is there a more clever solution?

Comment: You can split json parsing and filtering, source array `items` will be changed as well after loop run

Comment: Okey will try it later. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Nope sorry it change only the stock value in item and dont overwrite the items. 
Did you try it yourself already?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
        var json = "[{\"groupID\":\"12345\",\"subID\":\"71\",\"stock\":false,\"price\":\"32.21\"},{\"groupID\":\"12345\",\"subID\":\"25\",\"stock\":false,\"price\":\"12.94\"}]";
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StockData>>(json);
        foreach (var item in data.Where(d => d.Stock == false))
        {
            item.Stock = true;
        }
```

Where the StockData class will be:

```
public class StockData
{
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
    public string SubID { get; set; }
    public bool Stock { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

Good luck!